# Number of different clones of B lymphocytes

Tags: homework, immunology, antibody, immune-system

My professor told us that there are about a million different B cells based on their surface receptor.

I have read that we have about 30000 genes in all. Since receptors are proteins how do these 30000 genes make such a large number of receptors?
I read about something called alternative splicing. Is this the mechanism behind this?

Comment: You're looking for VDJ recombination: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V(D)J_recombination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate spicing of mRNA is a real phenomenon, but it's not the source of immune cell receptor diversity.  The **DNA** of immune cells is rearranged in a slightly random manner, to make a receptor with a random sequence in the variable portion of the receptor.  As Armatus already said, the process is VDJ recombination.  Here is a link to a textbook on NCBI

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK27113/

Answer (score 0):

Yes - in short, splicing enables one gene to be 'read' in multiple different ways. Imagine you have a set of letters; you can make one long word out of them, or cut some words out to make a shorter, different word. The same logic applies to gene expression, in that one gene could be made to code for a variety of different proteins (in this example, surface receptors).